# Сравнение значений полей ввода

Tags: javascript

Имеется два поля `<input type="text" name="diag_nap_uchr"  />` и `<input type="text" name="diag_osn"  />`. Как сравнить их значения в яваскрипте?
Функция (см. ниже) не очень то работает.

```
function srav(){
  if (forma.diag_nap_uchr.value===forma.diag_osn.value){
    alert ("Совпадение");
  }
}
```

Сравнили. И чтоб результат совпадения/несовпадения выдавался на странице? Вот это тоже сложность.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В полях укажите не name, а id (или можно оба сразу):

```
<input type="text" id="diag_nap_uchr"  />
<input type="text" id="diag_osn"  />
```

А в JavaScript пользуйтесь `document.getElementById()`, чтобы получить элемент:

```
function srav(){    
  var diag_nap_uchr = document.getElementById('diag_nap_uchr');  
  var diag_osn = document.getElementById('diag_osn');
  if (diag_nap_uchr.value === diag_osn.value){
    alert ("Совпадение");
  }
}
```

Чтобы вывести результат на страницу, можно добавить `<span>` в разметку и аналогично писать в его value сообщение.